# Join two large volumne of PCollection has performance issue

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Join two Pcollection with CoGroupsByKey approach taking hours to execute the 8+ millions records. Noted from another stackoverflow post [CoGbkResult has more than 10000 elements,reiteration (which may be slow) is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136919/cogbkresult-has-more-than-10000-elements-reiteration-which-may-be-slow-is-requ?rq=1) that "CoGbkResult has more than 10000 elements, reiteration (which may be slow) is required."

Any suggestion to improve this performance using this approach.

Here is the code snippet,

```java
PCollection<TableRow> pc1 = ...;
PCollection<TableRow> pc2 = ...;

WithKeys<String, TableRow> withKeyValue = 
  WithKeys.of((TableRow row) -> String.format("%s",row.get("KEYNAME")))
          .withKeyType(TypeDescriptors.strings());

PCollection<KV<String,TableRow>> keyed_pc1 =
  pc1.apply("WithKeys", withKeyValue );

PCollection<KV<String,TableRow>> keyed_pc2 = 
  pc2.apply("WithKeys", withKeyValue );

// (org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.Join class)
PCollection<KV<String,KV<TableRow,TableRow>>> joinedCollection = 
  Join.innerJoin(keyed_pc1, keyed_pc2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Beam specification doesn't define the execution of the join, and there is no faster way of writing inner joins yourself other than the SDK. Thus, the answer to this question depends on what is executing the join, i.e. which runner. I don't know the Flink or Spark runners, so this answer will be specific to the Dataflow runner.

If you haven't already, take a look at this blog post on this [topic](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/joining-and-shuffling-very-large-datasets-using-cloud-dataflow). In the blog post it describes the Dataflow Shuffle Service that can be manually enabled. This service is a better implementation than the current default and leads to much faster execution in general but especially for joins.

To enable Dataflow Shuffle Service, pass in the following [flags](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#cloud-dataflow-shuffle):

```
--experiments=shuffle_mode=service
--region=<allowed region>
```

Where the allowed regions for shuffle are: "us-central1", "europe-west1", "europe-west4", "asia-northeast1".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, this job is working on Dataflow Runner. As per documentation, enabled this shuffle service in my job by passing the mentioned parameter, but still job is running more than hour. I could not able to see any improvement on the performance aspect by enabling this service. Here is the other configuration that I used in this Job, it may be useful for you to provide me the further input of this analysis.  options.setDiskSizeGb(300); options.setNumWorkers(3); options.setMaxNumWorkers(50); options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-highmem-2"); options.setRegion("us-central1");

Comment: Given original description of the problem, shuffle is not the bottleneck. Hot key is. So I don't expect there will be much difference between shuffle service and default shuffle appliance in your case.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your join has a hot key: a key that has many entries and resulting entry does not fit in memory of a worker. This means that when you consume it later, it might cause to re fetch data that might slow performance.

Join.innerJoin still uses [CoGBK internally](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3b03106b55e8b7085190bf4a01218daf92276533/sdks/java/extensions/join-library/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.java#L70) to do join, so just using that library will not necessarily be more efficient. Order of iterating over collections might be important though.

If you have small pcollection on one side (fits into memory) you can use approach of lookup table for join. See [JoinAsLookup](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2cb44a81b258a64544fd8ca387305b2d5ccce13b/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/impl/transform/BeamJoinTransforms.java#L175) for reference.

If you have some means to know which key is hot, you can split it into smaller ones before join, but that requires more work on engineering side and some foreknowledge of data.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand that the hot key has many entries  and it does not fit in memory of a worker. Currently job used below configuration, please let me know if anything needs to be increased/reduced in order to improve the performance [options.setDiskSizeGb(300); options.setNumWorkers(3); options.setMaxNumWorkers(50); options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-highmem-2"); options.setRegion("us-central1");]. The JoinAsLookup transform is new to me, I will explore it and let you the feedback. Please share any sample for JoinAsLookup,much appreciated. Reference url is hard to understand

Comment: 1) You can try using machine with more memory available. That comes at higher cost though.
2) JoinAsLookup means that if one of your tables is small enough while other is big, you can convert smaller one into side input and utilize that side input for join. You will not have CoGBK at this point, but have a ParDo with side input. I don't have example at hand unfortunately. Will see if I can find one.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. At present working with SideInput Join, also exploring how can we split the large volume collection into the small collection before Joins the collection.