# Using CombineFn instead of CoGroupByKey to handle hotkeys

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a two very huge PCollections `<KV<Long,XYZ>>` and `<KV<Long,ABC>>`. I need to create a PCollection `<KV<XYZ,ABC>>` which I am able to using `CoGroupByKey.create()` transform. It works fine for smaller data set but in case of hotkeys it gets stuck. I am new to beam, I am trying to figure out how to use `CombineFn` to solve this. For now my code looks like this

```
final PCollection <KV<Long,XYZ>> xyzKV;
final PCollection <KV<Long,ABC>> abcKV;
final TupleTag<XYZ> t1 = new TupleTag<>();
final TupleTag<ABC> t1 = new TupleTag<>();
final PCollection <KV<XYZ,ABC>> combinedCollection = 
                               KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(t1, xyzKV).and(t2, abcKV)
    .apply(CoGroupByKey.create());
    
// this works fine but has performance issues in case of hotkeys.
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which runner you are using and what options they offer. A similar question is [Join two large volumne of PCollection has performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950728/join-two-large-volumne-of-pcollection-has-performance-issue).

If you are using the DataflowRunner, you can enable the shuffle service to speed up the process. However, according to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/shuffle-for-batch#use_shuffle), this option is currently enabled on Dataflow by default.